# Has anyone seen an Android app play a youtube video using the embedded player?

Tags: android, android-video-player

I've all but given up hope.  I want my application to play an embedded youtube video inside of my `LinearLayout`.  I tried a `WebView`, but the audio doesn't line up with the video, and the controls are not very responsive .  I tried RTSP, but that didn't work either.

I've seen the question asked here, and no one has been able to answer it.

All I want is to have my `VideoView` / `MediaPlayer` playing a youtube video with the `MediaController` controls.  Is this possible in Android?  Has anyone seen a youtube video actually play inside of an Android application?  The Youtube app does it, why can't anyone else?  Every youtube app I've downloaded either launches an `Intent` or it just doesn't work.

Comment: if you're going to give my question negative votes, at least explain why.  this is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: You say that you've "seen the question asked here". If that's so, then you probably shouldn't have re-posted it. Posting duplicate questions is generally discouraged. If you think you can improve the original question (and in the process, bump it up to the top), propose an edit to it. If not, consider setting a bounty on the question to motivate an answer. I'm not the person who downvoted this, but that could certainly be someone's rationale.

Comment: hi Cody. I wasn't reposting it, I was asking a different question. If anyone had actually seen an app play a youtube video, I was going to contact the developer and ask them how they did it.

Comment: These may help you,
Check this link: http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/downloads/list
and extract or import jar & follow the page
from: http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/w/list
with these you can play You-Tube video on android media player.

Answer (score 1):

In this code here is what I have done Marty,
I removed the MediaControllers from the UI and ran my youtube video stream threw rtsp and in my layout there is a basic VideoView with my needed button.  you can see this in real action here on the Android Markethttps://market.android.com/details?id=com.sbrecords&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5zYnJlY29yZHMiXQ..   video_url = "rtsp://v7.cache3.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwkeUryQ8ZkCqRMYJCAkFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3Jlc3VsdHNg6KnB9MbH8sVODA==/0/0/0/video.3gp";

```
        try {
                final VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
          //1   //mediaController = new MediaController(Splashscreen.this);
          //2   //mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                // Set video link (mp4 format )
                Uri video = Uri.parse(video_url);
                //videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                       videoView.start();
                    }
                });

             }catch(Exception e){
                  progressDialog.dismiss();
                 System.out.println("Video Play Error :"+e.getMessage());
             }
    // Thread to waste time while displaying splash screen
    Thread SplashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    // Wait given period of time
                    wait(7450000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }

            finish();
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  I downloaded your app and it doesn't work.  It says "Buffering video...." then eventually crashes.  As mentioned above, I can't get RTSP to work, and apparently neither can you.  Even if I could though, I would need to figure out the RTSP URL at runtime based on the Youtube ID.  thanks anyway.

Comment: Marty I am sorry that you are having problems using the above code. The application that you were directed to works just fine and is based inpart on the above code.There is no doubt that I have successfully completed the task that you have asked about ... now it's your turn. Post the RTSP Url link and lets see if your link is even ACTIVE.I mean you be experiencing the same problems your having with you website@www.martyspace.com whatever the case We are here to assist eachother and not degrade.So post your RTSP link and lets go from there,or edit your comment because my Application does WORK!

Comment: Also " I would need to figure out the RTSP URL at runtime based on the Youtube ID" I also have your answer for that ... so where is your RTSP link?

Comment: hi KaSiris, I'm sorry, I tried your app on the Kindle Fire, the Galaxy S2, and the Asus Transformer.  No go.  Just hangs on the "Buffering Video..." message.  I'm using Wifi only, perhaps this only works with a 3g connection?   anyways, here's a sample of a rtsp link that i'm trying to work with.  thanks!   rtsp://v8.cache6.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQn9QypHHVmt4RMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYLfE16GVmc-FTww=/0/0/0/video.3gp

Comment: Ok Marty, I have again tested and ran my rtsp feed again and the video feeds threw with No problem but your right ... your Link isn't working. So here is what I am doing, I am uploading a video to youtube on the swapping of the links and adding a third link to show that this is active, while I upload that video I ask that you view this short video on how to obtain Youtube rtsp http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA7Kkhv30WA ...

Comment: here is the swap video link marty.

Comment: hi KaSiris.  I appreciate your time, but I've tried everything you're saying.  RTSP links simply do not work for me.  And even if they did, it wouldn't work because my app reads in a text file of multiple youtube links. So my code would have to convert the youtube link to the rtsp link, and I don't think that is possible in the current version of Android.

Comment: Ok Marty, there is also a process for "reading in a text file of multiple youtube links". First thing first is getting your app to play 1 rtsp after you get that part in motion then I will faithfully assist you in completing the ladder of your app.